# Use Python 3.5 with matplotlib on Ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

When I use Python 3.5 on Ubuntu, with matplotlib installed, I get the error `no module named '_tkinter'` when I try to import matplotlib like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I tried installing tkinter, but the installation fails with the error that there's `no matching distribution`.

Comment: Do you try sudo apt-get install python3-tk?

Comment: yes,I have done,but,it said can‘t find matching distribution.